# Watson Assistant conversation_start do not work

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, facebook-messenger-bot, watson-assistant

I have a Watson Assistant integrated with Facebook Messenger and I need to sent a welcome message to the users when they start chatting. I used the conversation_start before for this but this time it's not working and I cannot figure out why!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsl84.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The conversation_start condition didn't work on the "Try it out" on the IBM-Cloud I think because the welcome condition works instead but it did work on FB messenger.

What caused this confusion: I was trying the conversation_start condition by entering an emoji (which worked for me before), but now it works only with text and doesn't work if the first user input is an emoji.